# How can I fetch data from an object which is a lookup in another object which is a lookup in another object which is a lookup in another object?

Tags: apex, soql

When I execute the below query, the output i get is list of Objects but not values. Can someone please shere some light on this query please.

```
SELECT cscfga__Product_Configuration__c.cscfga__Product_Definition__r.cscfga__Product_Category__r.Name FROM cscfga__Product_Configuration__c
```

Output:

```
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this soql in conga queries then you have to create a record of `Conga Query` object. There is a field `SOQL Select Statement` in `Conga Query` object. Write your soql as a value of that field and get the conga query record id and append it with the conga URL.

```
https://composer.congamerge.com ?SessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}&ServerUrl=
{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_290} &Id=[cscfga__Product_Configuration__c Id]&   
QueryId=[Conga Query Record Id]
```

After running this URL you can configure your template by clicking the `Template Builder` option.

Answer (score 0):

You are running this query in the Query editor, therefore you are getting Object as output.

```
for(cscfga__Product_Configuration__c object: [SELECT cscfga__Product_Configuration__c.cscfga__Product_Definition__r.cscfga__Product_Category__r.Name FROM cscfga__Product_Configuration__c]){
    System.debug(object.cscfga__Product_Configuration__c.cscfga__Product_Definition__r.cscfga__Product_Category__r.Name)
}
```

Comment: I want to use this query in conga queries to form report. Can you suggest how that can be achieved?